# React Native app connecting for Unity game [IOS] plugins folder missing

Tags: c#, react-native, unity-game-engine

we are building our native app with unity project.

The issue we are facing is:
When we follow this documentation https://github.com/azesmway/react-native-unity  everything is good but the plugin folder is missing. Do you have any help or suggestions why this folder is missing?

We have already tried upgrading Unity version to 2022.2.10f1 and
imported external dependency manager in case cocoa pods installation solve this issue.